# "on our town" vs "in our town"

Tags: prepositions

I saw the following sentence in a grammar textbook:

> The trip to Spain was very enjoyable, but we did not have much time to
>   explore and shop **on** our town.

Is "on our town" grammarly correct?

I just feel "in our town" is more appropriate.

Comment: Yes "to shop **in** our town" is more natural. You can throw leaflets **on** a town from an aircraft but not "shop **on** a town".

Comment: Is your town in Spain? You *visited* your own town? #justasking

Comment: It could also be a typo: ...to explore and shop [*on our **own***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_one's_own).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here and assume that your book has a typo.

With regard to the context (describing a vacation), any statement about "our town" is dubious. Would the writer really refer to the visited city as "our" city? Assuming a typo, you get a very standard sentence describing the slighly hectic schedule of a trip that left little time for individual activities.

> The trip to Spain was very enjoyable, but we did not have much time to explore and shop [on our **own**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_one's_own).

---

Back to your original question about **on** vs. **in** our town:

Yes, if you describe something you do at a certain place, it would be *in a town*.

*On a town* evokes a sense of "coming from above"- it rains *on* a town (or any other random object).

Comment: You are right. "on our own" makes much more sense. Thanks for your answer.